# DevExtreme Open site in app

Tags: ios, iphone, devexpress, devextreme

I am building an App with DevExtreme 17.1 basic application and replace my link with default link. The App works good in android and opens the site but it doesn't load the site in IOS and page remains white!

I have added the Phone Gap plugins like cordova-network-information and ... it doesn't load the site too. It is like the internet is disconnected but I can see the internet is connected.

I am trying to solve it but cant solved it somehow.

My HTML code is:

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'home', title: 'English Site' } " >
    <div class="home-view dx-content-background"  data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } " >

        <meta http-equiv="no-cache"> 
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ..bump..bump....followed link: **"*You can't view this ticket/Log in if this is your ticket*"**. Please post your code by modifying your question.

Comment: ... > correction < you posted the code but was not properly formatted and thus not shown... Made an edit to show your code. Should be shown once edit is approved. ...Web-pages and showing HTML-code ;p